# don't know why my mainnet txpool is empty

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

My geth node is sync'd but in the console, I don't see any pending transactions. Wanting to find a way to peek at pending transactions that other nodes have shared with my node.

Perhaps it is because my node has not fully sync'd yet. Not sure how to confirm if that's the case.

```
> eth.getBlock('pending', true).transactions
[]
>
> eth.getBlock('pending', true).transactions
[]
> txpool.content
{
  pending: {},
  queued: {}
}
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 0
}
```

Comment: What does `eth.blockNumber` returns?

Comment: @Ismael It's zero. Is that indicating initial fast sync has not completed, and how do I tell how much is left for fast sync? I have: Imported new block headers               count=171  elapsed=419.093ms number=5343443 hash=b54eae…787209 ignored=0 ... and Imported new state entries               count=2304 elapsed=8.641ms   processed=83043397 pending=9920  retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0 ... and Imported new state entries               count=1674 elapsed=6.888ms   processed=83045071 pending=9888  retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0.

Comment: Yes, your node has not finished syncing. If you have an SSD it should take less than a couple of days.

Comment: @Ismael I do but it's taken longer than that. Is there any way to tell how far along it is?

Comment: You can use `eth.syncing` to check progress, but I'm afraid in last release of geth it will erroneously show as synced whenit still didn't finish .